# Where is __dso_handle defined?

Tags: linker, llvm, libstdc++

I have an unresolved symbol error when trying to compile my program which complains that it cannot find `__dso_handle`. Which library is this function usually defined in?

Does the following result from `nm on libstdc++.so.6` mean it contains that?

I tried to link against it but the error still occurs.

```
nm libstdc++.so.6 | grep dso
00000000002fc480 d __dso_handle
```

Answer (score 25):

`__dso_handle` is a "guard" that is [used to identify dynamic shared objects during global destruction](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#dso-dtor-runtime-api).

Thom Chiovoloni [wrote](https://gist.github.com/thomcc/8c4a8003cf1a282949a539e899cb45aa) a concise description of `__dso_handle` while debugging issues related to it:

> `__dso_handle` is a magic symbol that has a different value in every `.so` (it's a hidden symbol provided by the loader). It's used ... to let the runtime ("the runtime" = libc + loader + ...) know which shared library the thread local dtor applies to, which allows the runtime to avoid some cases where it would call a function pointer coming from an unloaded module.

Realistically, you should stop reading here. If you're trying to defeat object identification by messing with `__dso_handle`, something is likely very wrong.

However, since you asked where it is defined: the answer is complex. To surface the location of its definition (for GCC), use `iostream` in a C++ file, and, after that, do `extern int __dso_handle;`. That should surface the location of the declaration due to a type conflict (see [this forum thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/fyi-shared-libs-and-iostream-c-331113/) for a source).

Sometimes, it is [defined manually](https://lists.debian.org/debian-gcc/2003/07/msg00057.html).

Sometimes, it is defined/supplied by the "runtime" installed by the compiler (in practice, the CRT is usually just a bunch of binary header/entry-point-management code, and some exit guards/handlers). In GCC (not sure if other compilers support this; if so, it'll be in their sources):

- [Main definition](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/config/ia64/crtbegin.S#L44)
- [Testing `__dso_handle` replacement/tracker example 1](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/testsuite/g++.dg/init/dso_handle1.C)
- [Testing `__dso_handle` replacement/tracker example 2](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/testsuite/g++.dg/init/dso_handle2.C)

Often, it is defined in the stdlib:

- [Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/gingerbread/libc/private/__dso_handle.S)
- [BSD](ftp://ftp.fau.de/netbsd/misc/repositories/hg/src.git/lib/csu/common/crtbegin.c)

Further reading:

- [Subtle bugs caused by `__dso_handle` being unreachable in some compilers](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2011-March/228106.html)

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this problem. Here are the conditions which seem to reliably generate the trouble:

1. g++ linking without the C/C++ standard library: `-nostdlib` (typical small embedded scenario).
2. Defining a statically allocated standard library object; specific to my case is `std::vector`. Previously this was `std::array` statically allocated without any problems. Apparently not all `std::` statically allocated objects will cause the problem.
3. Note that I am not using a shared library of any type.
4. [GCC/ARM cross compiler](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) is in use.

If this is your use case then merely add the command line option to your compile/link command line: `-fno-use-cxa-atexit`

Here is a very good link to the [__dso_handle usage as 'handle to dynamic shared object'](http://wiki.osdev.org/C%2B%2B#GCC).

There appears to be a typo in the page, but I have no idea who to contact to confirm:

<s>After you have called the objects' constructor destructors GCC automatically calls the function ...</s>

I think this should read "Once all destructors have been called GCC calls the function" ...

One way to confirm this would be to implement the `__cxa_atexit` function as mentioned and then single step the program and see where it gets called. I'll try that one of these days, but not right now.

Comment: Will this cause memory leaks, considering the other answer?

Comment: adding -fno-use-cxa-atexit made no change in error output for me. My error:

undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
I'm using -nostdlib in my g++ call

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @natersoz's answer-

For me, using `-Wabi-tag -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` alongside `-fno-use-cxa-atexit` helped compile an old lib. A telltale is if the C++ functions in the error message have `std::__cxx11` in them, due to an [ABI change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417707/glibcxx-use-cxx11-abi-gcc-4-8-and-abi-compatibility).