# What is __dso_handle and why does it need to be defined for linking to work?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, linker-errors, static-linking

I was recently attempting to build some files in C and C++ for an AWS machine and received the linker error `__dso_handle is not defined`. This stymied me for some time as I reviewed several pieces that mentioned it, including [Where is __dso_handle defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308720/where-is-dso-handle-defined) and [modm-io/modm#793](https://github.com/modm-io/modm/issues/793). All I have gathered is that it is used somehow for deallocating static objects in the global scope, that something in the C++ library needs it, and that usually it is defined in some obscure location, but not always. I was ultimately directed to, as a quick-and-dirty hack for the moment, put in a .cpp file the following line:

```
extern "C" void *__dso_handle = NULL;
```

and now that this symbol was defined, the linking succeeded just fine. I have been told that this is *not* an appropriate long-term solution, and indeed, according to the above SO link:

> If you're trying to defeat object identification by messing with `__dso_handle`, something is likely very wrong.

Indeed, this may be. My question(s) are:

1. What exactly is the purpose of the `__dso_handle` variable (preferably in more detail than the SO link above, as while it said what the variable is, it was not clear to me how it's used).
2. Why would a system be unable to find it - if it's so important for the C++ standard library to work, why wouldn't the C++ standard library define it?
3. What, if anything, is liable to go wrong with a manual definition such as the one above? If I understand [this](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#dso-dtor-runtime-api) Itanium page correctly, this means it will not be able to find the address of object segments when the program exits and thus cannot free them correctly.
4. What is a better way to define `__dso_handle` than defining it in a program source file as I did?

Note: I cannot provide the code in question as it is proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an embedded device which will not exit the program so you will never call atexit function directly or indirectly.

> Why would a system be unable to find it - if it's so important for the
> C++ standard library to work, why wouldn't the C++ standard library
> define it?

Because this library was never intended to be used on embedded bare metal systems only in the hosted environment - assuming normal program termination. Bare metal versions are only adaptations and they still have many issues. Your question is wrong (why?) as it was never intended and it is a random bug.

> What exactly is the purpose of the __dso_handle variable (preferably
> in more detail than the SO link above, as while it said what the
> variable is, it was not clear to me how it's used).

Bare metal systems do not use it as they do not exit. It is not needed

> What, if anything, is liable to go wrong with a manual definition such
> as the one above? If I understand this Itanium page correctly, this
> means it will not be able to find the address of object segments when
> the program exits and thus cannot free them correctly.

It is a dirty workaround of a not very well completed standard library port. I would not define it as NULL, only as a pointer to the function resetting uC.